# Questions about Activity and Fragment lifecycle

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-lifecycle

I trace lifecycle method's callback from `Activity` and `Fragment` components and i have a lot of questions. I need you help to understand some points.

Situation 1:

One **launcher Activity** with one **Fragment**, which filled it. When app started, Fragment become active and user see only Fragment.

Lyfecycle:

1. Activity: onCreate
2. Activity: onStart
3. Fragment: onAttach
4. Fragment: onCreate
5. Fragment: onCreateView
6. Fragment: onViewCreated
7. Fragment: onActivityCreated
8. Activity: onResume
9. Fragment: onResume.

Questions:

1) There is no `onResume` between 2 - 3, because of **Activity** lose focus?

2) I don't think i understand what happen on 8 - 9. It seems like some kind of "switch focus" between Fragment and Activity. Ok, i can understand: 9 is about Fragment came to the foreground, take focus and `onResume` was called. But what is 8? When i load Fragment(since 3), Activity is never on foreground.

Situation 2:

Like situation 1, but now `Fragment` and `Activity` loaded and i pressed **Home**:

1. Activity: onPause
2. Fragment: onPause
3. Activity: onStop
4. Fragment: onStop

Questions:

When i run it, i expect another behavior. I thought Fragment should be the first who called stop methods, like (Fragment onPause -> Fragment onStop - > Activity methods). Why it worked this way?

Situation 3:

Like situation 2, **Activity** with **Fragment** are back to the foreground. I remember, they both have `Stopped` status (because of `onStop` was called).

1. Activity: onStart
2. Activity: onResume
3. Fragment: onResume

Questions:

I expect 1-2, but i expect that **Fragment** call `onStart`, because, if i understand it correct, `onStart` called when fragment become visible. Why `onStart` was't called?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fragment and Activity lifecycles work in parallel. The linear dependence between their lifecycle ends as soon as both activity and fragment are created.

The [following figure](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/the-android-lifecycle-cheat-sheet-part-iii-fragments-afc87d4f37fd) explains how the two lifecycles are interconnected.

[image]

Note that `onStart` and `onResume` (and similarly, `onStop` and `onPause`) for both fragment and activity execute in parallel and there is no guarantee of order. Sometimes fragment will take precedence over activity, and vice versa.

The only guarantee is that activity's `onCreate` will always be called first. After that, fragment acts on its own.